# List comprehension and answer output

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When solving NQueens on LeetCode, my answer array would never be correct despite my logic being sound.

After looking at a submission, I changed my definition of **board** which then accepted my solution. I don't understand what was wrong with my initial definition though.

board = [["." for i in range(n)] for i in range(n)]

board_Not_Working = [["."]*n]*n #Initial definition